# How can I set a negative value as the initial value of an index variable?

Tags: rust, indexing

How can I set the initial value of an index variable for an array as -1? The index variable data type needs to be usize and value of usize can not be negative.

I want to do this:

```
let mut i: usize = -1;
let mut array: [i32; 10] = [0; 10];

i += 1;
let data = array[i];
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: An unknown value is best depicted via `Option`

Comment: Usually you can use iterators and avoid indexing altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing some sort of iteration that might be better expressed another way, and even if not you can probably increment the `usize` after using it for the first time instead of before. But if neither of those apply, there is always [`wrapping_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.wrapping_add):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut i = usize::MAX;
    i = i.wrapping_add(1);
    println!("{i}");  // 0
}
```

Comment: I prefer using `isize` and casting over `wrapping_add()`. It can have the same efficiency, or, if efficiency isn't a requirement it can have more safety (by using `try_into()`), and it is much less obscure and more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Iterators are not always the answer. In other languages one would start with 0 and simply use `array[i++]` – it's beyond me why  Rust omitted something so useful.

I had this as part of a macro's loop, and my best attempt was a horrible block expression.

```rust
$(... array[{ /* clumsy i++ */ i += 1; i - 1 }] ...)+
```

Comment: By "so useful" do you refer to the postfix `++` operator? Because as useful as it can be, it is also confusing in the same amount. Rust just requires two steps for that, it does not make it impossible. But I still don't see how this answers OP's question. Yes, usually you can start from 0, but sometimes the increment has to come first and so you need to start from -1.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm open to any example that show one must start to -1

Comment: I prefer use my own replace instead of your macro https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6fe320802b74d1fc9d29808cbd69fee2 or you can even do that https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dab27cb8f8b258d9c0f905b50c2b44bc

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Not sure what confuses some people about ++/--. Place it before the variable, and you get the result of perfoming it *before* returning. Place it after, and it gets performed *after* setting aside the value to return. If this is taught to noobs like that (maybe with examples), should be crystal clear.

Comment: @Stargateur Ok both of these work. The 2nd is even useful, it it were part of the language. (Not sure why Acc(umulator) – I'd call it PostIncrement.) Some such would be a way to implement syntactic sugar `i++` 

Answer (score -6):

1. index data types must be of usize
2. but usize can not be negative

solution: use type casting using as keyword

```
let data = array[i as usize];
```

Comment: that not a solution that just trowing away the purpose of Rust.

Comment: @Stargateur Instead of merely postulating, care to explain why a valid workaround "throws away a purpose"?

Comment: @Daniel "it's beyond me why  Rust omitted something so useful." look you just hate/don't understand rust. Purpose of Rust is robustness, safe and correct code. Using a `isize` is wrong by nature for indexing.

Comment: @Stargateur Wow – you're getting wilder here! I happen to love Rust more than any other language. Which is not to say it's perfect. Missing something that's in most other languages, and giving an example where I needed a clumsy work around is a far shot from hate.